# Revolving a circle around x-axis

Tags: calculus

While revolving the circle around x-axis, I got very confused with a simple yet difficult question. So, if i were to revolve this around x-axis.[image] Does it give the same volume when revolving the whole circle around x-axis?

Comment: Yes. If we take the former, then $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, and if we take the latter, $y = \pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Therefore, $y^2 = r^2-x^2$ in both cases, so $\pi\int_{-r}^{r}y^2 dx$ will be equivalent in both cases. (You can also think of it as getting a sphere in either case, except you can simply revolve the whole circle by only half a revolution.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  You get a whole ball either way.  For the whole disk you only have to rotate it by $\pi$ while for the half disk you have to rotate it by $2\pi$.  The added rotation angle makes up for the smaller rotating area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to rotate the half-circle by $360^\circ$, while when you rotate the full circle, it's enough to make a $180^\circ$ rotation.